# Google Action - Custom Reprompt is ignored when using List Option helper

Tags: actions-on-google

I have noticed that the Google Assistant ignores my reprompt message when I use the List Option helper ([documenation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#list_and_carousel_option)). Instead of outputting my reprompt SSML the last output is being repeated with the system-default reprompt ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts#system-default_reprompts)). Via the simulator I am not able to get my custom reprompt message even though I choose Google Home as virtual test device and click on the 'simulate no input' button after my action has sent the response with the custom reprompt message ('Repeat again or would you like more?'). There is no notice in the documentation that the reprompt is ignored when using the List Option helper ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#inputprompt))

My response looks like this (including the custom reprompt messages):

```
{
    "conversationToken": "token",
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [{
        "inputPrompt": {
            "richInitialPrompt": {
                "items": [{
                    "simpleResponse": {
                        "ssml": "<speak>Choose between item 1, 2 and 3.</speak>",
                        "displayText": "I have the following for you:"
                    }
                }],
                "suggestions": [
                    {
                       "title": "more"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "noInputPrompts": [
                {
                    "ssml": "<speak>Repeat again or would you like more?</speak>"
                },
                {
                    "ssml": "<speak>Repeat again or would you like more?</speak>"
                },
                {
                    "ssml": "<speak>See you next time.</speak>"
                }
            ]
        },
        "possibleIntents": [{
                "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
                "inputValueData": {
                    "listSelect": {
                        "title": "item list",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "optionInfo": {
                                    "key": "item1"
                                },
                                "title": "item 1",
                                "description": "description item 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "optionInfo": {
                                    "key": "item2"
                                },
                                "title": "item 2",
                                "description": "description item 2"
                            },
                            {
                                "optionInfo": {
                                    "key": "item3"
                                },
                                "title": "item 3",
                                "description": "description item 3"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec"
                }
            },
            {
                "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Trying to simulate no input has been driving me crazy all afternoon, as I kept getting the response _"The agent returned an empty TTS."_ and nothing in the logs. Turns out that the simulator was set to "phone", not "device"! Posting this here just in case it helps anyone else..